# Android as GSM basestation

Tags: gsm

Is that possible to turn an Android GSM into a basestation? 
For example, if it can send and receive data then it can emulate that even if it's for an only device, if it was that simple there were no such a big need for other stations. And if you have a link or doc or something that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. The baseband itself runs its own custom firmware which is not available for modification by the Android OS. If you could modify the baseband firmware, it would be theoretically possible to do this. Note that this may be illegal in some jurisdictions.